# What is the most idiomatic way of representing errors in F#

Tags: error-handling, f#

I'm working on F# project and I wonder what is the best practice to return domain error using `Result` type in F#. There are several ways of doing it which I consider:

**Inherited exceptions**

```
type DomainException(message) =
    inherit Exception(message)

type ItemNotFoundException(item) =
    inherit DomainException(sprintf "Item %s is not found" item)

let findItem item =
    match item with
    | Some x -> Ok x
    | None -> Error(new ItemNotFoundException("someitem"))
```

**Custom record type**

```
type DomainError =
    { Name : string
      Message : string }

let findItem item =
    match item with
    | Some x -> Ok x
    | None ->
        Error({ Name = "ItemNotFound"
                Message = "Item someitem is not found" })
```

**Discriminated union of record type**

```
type DomainErrorTypes =
    | ItemNotFoundError of DomainError
    | ItemInvalidFormat of DomainError

let findItem item =
    match item with
    | Some x -> Ok x
    | None ->
        { Name = "ItemNotFound"
          Message = "Item someitem is not found" }
        |> ItemNotFoundError
        |> Error
```

So which way is more idiomatic and convenient to use? I also will be happy to see better options.

Comment: Normally we use Result to convey outcomes that are part of the workflow, whether successes or errors. Exception handlers are often used to handle unexpected errors - that is, errors not considered part of the workflow, e.g. out of memory. Sometimes exception handlers are needed for functions that use exceptions as part of their expected outcomes, and these you can wrap in functions that return a Result.

Answer (score 6):

Typically it would be a discriminated union. Every error requires different details to accompany the message. For instance:

```
type DomainErrorTypes =
| ItemNotFound of ItemId
| FileNotFound of string
| InvalidFormat of format
| IncompatibleItems of Item * Item
| SQLError of code:int * message:string
| ...
```

You can also capture some exceptions (not necessarily all):

```
| ...
| Exception of exn
```

Comment: I would not call the DU `DomainErrorTypes`, though, but simply `DomainError`. (I know that was the OP's choice.)

Comment: The thing is that I need unified type to represent different kinds of errors to be able to parse them in another service easily.

Comment: You can use a function to convert from the DU to your unified type. `DomainErrorTypes -> string * string` that way you get the best of both worlds