# Elegant Solution for Discriminated Unions Representing Failures in F#

Tags: error-handling, f#, conventions

I’m moving away from creating and catching exceptions in F# to something built around `Result<'T, 'TError>`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650500/what-is-the-most-idiomatic-way-of-representing-errors-in-f), which agrees with my initial pursuit of representing failures with a discriminated union, but I ran into the problem of having a lot of different cases for my `Failure` discriminated union:

```
type TypedValue =
| Integer of int
| Long of int64
| …

type Failure =
| ArgumentOutOfRange of {| Argument : TypedValue; Minimum : TypedValue; Maximum : TypedValue |}
| BufferTooSmall of {| RequiredSize : int |}
| Exception of exn
| IndexOutOfRange of {| Index : int |}
| …
```

I’d prefer not to have a multitude of types dedicated to error handling. This “typed value” thing is not elegant at all as I either have to create conflicting names (`Byte` versus `System.Byte`) or create long names to avoid conflict (`| UnsignedByte of byte`).

Generics is a possibility, but then what would the `'T` in `Failure<'T>` represent? `ArgumentOutOfRange` wouldn’t be the only case in the discriminated union, and some cases might require more type parameters or none at all.

Comment: Failure<'T> is normally just a string - an error message. Stop building that Failure DU to cover everything. If you absolutely do need something more than a string, then as a general rule place the failure type(s) needed for that in the domain where they belong, along with the specific success type(s) if there are any.

Comment: And if you haven't discovered this yet, do read it carefully: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/

Comment: Also note that the Result type is a special case of the Choice type, which gives you more than two possible outcomes. Not saying you should start to use that for error handling in a lot of places, but just be aware of its usefulness.

Comment: Exceptions has a common base class, it would be quite difficult in the languages we usually use to have to declare a union exception class of every type. I think one can make a similar argument that the `Failure` type should only have a few relevant cases where one case is common base class. The Message ie string also makes sense to me (which I for error handling see as a limit common "base" class).

Answer (score 3):

Using `Result<'T, 'TError>` makes a lot of sense in cases where you have custom kinds of errors that you definitely need to handle or in cases where you have some other logic for propagating errors than the one implemented by standard exceptions (e.g. if you can continue running code despite the fact that there was an error). However, I would not use it as a 1:1 replacement for exceptions - it will just make your code unnecessarilly complicated and cumbersome without really giving you much benefits.

To answer your question, since you are mirroring standard .NET exceptions in your discriminated union, you could probably just use a standard .NET exception in your `Result` type and use `Result<'T, exn>` as your data type:

```
if arg < 10 then Error(ArgumentOutOfRangeException("arg", "Value is too small"))
else OK(arg - 1)
```

Regarding the `ArgumentOutOfRange` union case and `TypedValue` - the reason for using something like `TypedValue` is typically that you need to pattern match on the possible values and do something with them. In case of exceptions, what do you want to do with the values? If you just need to report them to the user, then you can use `obj` which will let you easily print them (it won't be that easy to get the numerical values and do some further calculations with them, but I don't think you need that).

```
type Failure = 
  | ArgumentOutOfRange of {| Argument : obj; Minimum : obj; Maximum : obj |}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option (and what I normally do, personally) is to model your domain-specific failures with specific cases in your `Failure` union, and then have a general-purpose `UnexpectedError` case that takes an `exn` as its data and handles any non-domain-related failures.  Then, when an error from one domain occurs in another, you can use `Result.mapError` to convert between them.  Here's an example from a real domain I've modeled:

```
open System

// Top-level domain failures
type EntityValidationError =
| EntityIdMustBeGreaterThanZero of int64
| InvalidTenant of string
| UnexpectedException of exn

// Sub-domain specific failures
type AccountValidationError =
| AccountNumberMustBeTenDigits of string
| AccountNameIsRequired of string
| EntityValidationError of EntityValidationError // Sub-domain representaiton of top-level failures
| AccountValidationUnexpectedException of exn

// Sub-domain Entity
// The fields would probably be single-case unions rather than primitives 
type Account =
    {
        Id: int64 
        AccountNumber: string
    }

module EntityId =
    let validate id =
        if id > 0L
        then Ok id
        else Error (EntityIdMustBeGreaterThanZero id)

module AccountNumber =
    let validate number =
        if number |> String.length = 10 && number |> Seq.forall Char.IsDigit
        then Ok number
        else Error (AccountNumberMustBeTenDigits number)

module Account =
    let create id number =
        id 
        |> EntityId.validate
        |> Result.mapError EntityValidationError // Convert to sub-domain error type
        |> Result.bind (fun entityId ->
            number 
            |> AccountNumber.validate
            |> Result.map (fun accountNumber -> { Id = entityId; AccountNumber = accountNumber }))
```